# Modifying assembly instructions before loading

Tags: c++, assembly, instructions, disassembly

I have a DLL that I need to load (I have written it and compiled it), and I would like to insert instructions between existing instructions of the assembly code before loading the DLL into memory. Of course, you can't just read every byte and insert them between there because instructions sometimes are multiple bytes.

I was thinking of using something like Udis86 and reading instructions one by one and then writing them to memory, and between them writing my other instructions. Is this a good approach or is there something better?

Comment: Is this a DLL you have written or otherwise have control over?  Or is it an off-the-shelf DLL needing modification?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have written and compiled the DLL.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.  Sorry, I haven't a clue what the answer is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (at least) two choices:

- open the DLL file and modify it using file read/write operations
- load the DLL and modify the instructions before they execute

Both are possible, though with the latter it will be necessary to circumvent or disable security protection:  code (as opposed to data) is loaded into memory which is not writable in most (if not all—not sure about CE) Windows environments.

With the code loaded, there is direct o/s support to find symbol addresses.  Modifying a file will require either advanced knowledge about decoding the symbol information and interpreting the file offset, or searching for patterns placed in the file specifically for the purpose.  This can be logic in the DllMain entry point which is called to initialize the DLL, or any other function within the DLL which is known to execute early enough.

There are also the techniques of [DLL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) which could accomplish the same ends.

---

But, Instead of all this, what about arranging for the DLL to use some callback function  pass to it once you've composed the code to execute?  It's hard to tell what's useful without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish.

---

As for how to do it, an easy way is to write the instructions in an assembly module, assemble it, and then examine the generated bytes.  Naturally, you should thoroughly understand the target assembly language so that branch and relative jump offsets—as well as data references—are computed or fixed up correctly.  While is it possible and sometimes practical to disassemble instructions at runtime, it's usually easier to have already identified the instructions through some other means (like a debugger) and have the program look for the byte sequence and then perform whatever transformations are needed.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Shifting instructions is not a good idea. Many x86 instructions are dependent on their position, so if you shift them you'll likely break a lot of things.
What you could do instead is copy the instruction at the place you need to patch; patch there a jmp to some free area, then in that free area put the copied instruction, your extra code and then finally a jmp back to the original code. Not trivial but doable. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/LibMinHook.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mini_hook_engine.aspx) for possible implementations.
That said, *why* do you need to modify the binary when you could just modify the source instead? You should ask the *actual* question, not "how to do X [because I decided I need X to solve my problem]".

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure where you are trying to insert the code. But if it is in the middle of the function body and not necessarily the function prologue or epilogue, then why dont you use an __asm block with a bunch of nop's to pad the area that you would write the code into. Then just fill in the code where the nop's are at runtime.

Comment: That won't work for this application, but as an unrelated question, does a compiler normally generate NOPs in code, or would the NOPs you add be the only NOPs in the entire file?

Comment: @SamJam: Pretty sure that compilers make fairly judicious use of NOPs, for example, when doing instruction alignment.